# Communication Xbee S1 Coordinator to End Device

Tags: xbee, python

I am new in the Xbee world. I have four Xbees S1 802.15.4; three are end devices and one is a coordinator.

The end devices transmit well to the coordinator. The coordinator is connected to a Raspberry Pi via USB with an Xbee USB Explorer. The communication is through serial and I can see the data for the end devices, using Python.

How can I send a signal from the coordinator to each end device to wait to start the transmission?

At this moment I have the configuration in API Mode.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a Python XBee library, and use it to send a "Broadcast Message", which means it will go to all the end devices.

A Broadcast message is addressed like so:

> The 64-bit destination address should be set to 0x000000000000FFFF for
> a broadcast transmission (to all devices). The coordinator can be
> addressed by either setting the 64-bit address to all 0x00s and the
> 16-bit address to 0xFFFE, OR by setting the 64-bit address to the
> coordinator's 64-bit address and the 16-bit address to 0x0000. For all
> other transmissions, setting the 16-bit address to the correct 16-bit
> address can help improve performance when transmitting to multiple
> destinations. If a 16-bit address is not known, this field should be
> set to 0xFFFE (unknown).

If you don't want to use a library, you can build the packet yourself using the Reference for your version of XBee (eg. https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/pdfs/90000976.pdf) and look at the section for "ZigBee Transmit Request Frame type: 0x10". Send data matching that format and it should work.

But I'd recommend using a library.